# Select output writer for Pandoc in the YAML metablock

Tags: markdown, pandoc

In order to specify an output format for pandoc, I must set the `-t` flag on the command line. I would like to specify which output format I want from inside of my Markdown text file. Is this possible?

For instance, if I wanted pandoc to convert my Markdown text file to a Microsoft Word document, I imagine it might look like this:

mydocument.md:

```
---
title: Not Just Good, More Good
author: DanielTA
date: 9 September 2022
geometry: margin=1in
mainfont: Comic Neue
fontsize: 12pt
output: docx
---

Document body text...
```

Then run `pandoc mydocument.md` which would output `mydocument.docx` into the same directory.

I tried this and it does not seem to work. I know that many command line variables can be defined in the YAML metablock header, but I am not sure if format/output options are possible to define there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to define this kind of information in the metadata. However, pandoc has a feature called "[defaults files](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#defaults-files)". Input and output formats, options, and filenames can all be put there. The file is then passed to pandoc via `--defaults` or `-D`.

```
pandoc -D docx.yaml mydocument.md
```

Alternatively, take a look at [Quarto](https://quarto.org). It is a beautiful system based on pandoc and allows to incorporate this kind of info directly in the YAML frontmatter.

Comment: I was under impression that this is easy to implement with lua writer.
But not with "docx" (see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76143659/2520247)
What is wrong in my custom writer?

Comment: @johndoe There's a difference between plain-text writers (like HTML) and binary writers (like docx). The former requires a `Writer` Lua function, the latter `ByteStringWriter`. That's why your writer doesn't quite work. You'll get closer by always using ByteStringWriter.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy to implement with [lua writer](https://pandoc.org/custom-writers.html) using [`pandoc.write`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.write) function.

```
function Writer (doc, opts)
  local fmt = doc.meta.output[1].text
  local template = pandoc.template
  opts.template = template.compile(template.default(fmt))
  return pandoc.write(doc, fmt, opts)
end

function Template ()
  return""
end
```

And this works as expected for most of the formats.
But not with "docx".